# How to subtract EntityFunctions.TruncateTime from custom time

Tags: c#

I have a query which returns true or false depending on two conditions. One of the conditions is check whether the time (today's time) from the DB is less than or equal to 5 minutes (i.e 300 seconds).
I tried defining a variable of DateTime format as follows

```
System.DateTime customDate= new System.DateTime(0000, 00, 00, 0, 00, 300);
```

here is the query

```
bool result = (from a in this.db.Samples
               where a.Ping == "Online" 
               && 
              (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.date) - DateTime.Now) <= customDate                 
               select a).Any();
```

but I have the following error

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan?'
>   and System.DateTime'

kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting one `DateTime` from another results in a `TimeSpan`. EntityFramework doesn't support DateTime/TimeSpan arithmetic so you'll have to use the DiffMinutes entity function. ([Full list of entity functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx)).

Try:

```
bool result = (from a in this.db.Samples
               where a.Ping == "Online" 
               && 
               EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.date), DateTime.Now) <= 5
               select a).Any();
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, but I have the following error - "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type".

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the need for the Entity Functions for any kind of DateTime/TimeSpan arithmetic. You can use the DiffMinutes Entity Function to get the difference in minutes between a start and end date.

Comment: Yes, the 5 is minutes. The Diff functions all return an Int32 so you could use DiffSeconds if you wanted to get the difference in seconds. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx for all of the Diff functions.