# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The following throws an error:

```
public FieldViewer GetFieldViewByFieldIDIPAndUserByDate( int fieldID, string ip, string userID, DateTime date )
{
    return this.context.FieldViewers.Where( x =>
        x.Field.FieldID == fieldID &&
        x.Viewer.IPAddress == ip &&
        x.Viewer.User.Id == userID &&

        date.Subtract( x.Viewer.CreatedAt ).TotalMinutes >= 10 ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How do I go about solving this as I need to subtract per query instead.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395530(v=vs.110).aspx possibly? example usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486218/how-to-subtract-entityfunctions-truncatetime-from-custom-time

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities for subtracting 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570858/linq-to-entities-for-subtracting-2-dates)

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix this is to perform that part of the filtering outside of the LINQ to Entities provider, using the LINQ to Objects provider. To do that, append a call to `AsEnumerable()` before that operation:

```
public FieldViewer GetFieldViewByFieldIDIPAndUserByDate( int fieldID, string ip, string userID, DateTime date )
{
    return this.context.FieldViewers.Where( x =>
            x.Field.FieldID == fieldID &&
            x.Viewer.IPAddress == ip &&
            x.Viewer.User.Id == userID)
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Where(x => date.Subtract( x.Viewer.CreatedAt ).TotalMinutes >= 10)
       .FirstOrDefault();  
}
```

Another way is to use one of the [specialized LINQ to Entities operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx), like [`DiffMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395530(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes` for your case will be inefficient. You should do this way

```
public FieldViewer GetFieldViewByFieldIDIPAndUserByDate( int fieldID, string ip, string userID, DateTime date )
{
    var tenMinThreshold = date - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    return this.context.FieldViewers.Where( x =>
        x.Field.FieldID == fieldID &&
        x.Viewer.IPAddress == ip &&
        x.Viewer.User.Id == userID &&
        x.Viewer.CreatedAt <= tenMinThreshold).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to  find the difference in minutes:

`EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(date, x.Viewer.CreatedAt) >= 10`

Sources:

[How to subtract EntityFunctions.TruncateTime from custom time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486218/how-to-subtract-entityfunctions-truncatetime-from-custom-time)

[EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395530(v=vs.110).aspx)

As this api is now obsolete (thanks for pointing this out @Jimmyt1988), instead use: [DbFunctions.DiffMinutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffminutes(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTimeOffset%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTimeOffset%7D))

Comment: `EntityFunctions is obsolete, you can use DbFunctions`. Thanks for this it works great and does it before the db call!